# Python error: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tryng to run this code to generate some graphics but everytime this error appears.
parte of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(8, sharex=False, sharey=False,figsize=(15,15))
fig.suptitle('Todas Features para estado Normal ')
for i in data_n.columns:
    axs[i].plot(data_n[i])
    axs[i].set_title('Coluna {} do Dataset'.format(i))
```

error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-0fef11f34a8c> in <module>
      3 fig.suptitle('Todas Features para estado Normal ')
      4 for i in data_n.columns:
----> 5     axs[i].plot(data_n[i])
      6     axs[i].set_title('Coluna {} do Dataset'.format(i))

IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8
```

when i try to change de number os subplots, nothing changes.

Comment: You've created eight subplots.  Obviously `data_n.columns` is bigger than 8.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your `data_n` variable is but I'm guessing it's probably a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) object.

Python `for` loops are 0-indexed and your `IndexError` error is occuring at index 8, so `data_n.columns` is probably an iterable `pandas.DataFrame.columns` object that has more than 8 values. You can check this with `len(data_n.columns)`.

Consider trying:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(data_n.columns), sharex=False, sharey=False,figsize=(15,15))
fig.suptitle('Todas Features para estado Normal ')
for i in data_n.columns:
    axs[i].plot(data_n[i])
    axs[i].set_title('Coluna {} do Dataset'.format(i))
```

This will only work if the names of the data_n columns are integers, which they may or may not be. To handle column names such as `col1`,`col2`, etc. you'll need to use an integer index, as in this basic example:

```
indexer = 0
for i in data_n.columns:
    axs[indexer].plot(data_n[i])
    axs[indexer].set_title('Coluna {} do Dataset'.format(i))
    indexer += 1
```